# How to investigate and remove Trojan:EC2/DGADomainRequest.B

Tags: amazon-ec2, malware-removal, malware-detection

My GuardDuty management console on Amazon shows that my server is infected with malware:

> "EC2 instance i-7e1d4356 is querying algorithmically generated
>   domains. Such domains are commonly used by malware and could be an
>   indication of a compromised EC2 instance"

It is querying `fkg2f0c33okxznr2nknk7jdhaozrz2ul.com`

I checked the access log and found these entries "attempt of SQL injection"

```
79.174.12.136 - - [25/Mar/2019:15:30:45 +0000] "GET /company/registration.php?pid=211111111111111111111111111'%20UNION%20SELECT%20(select%20CONCAT(CHAR(91,88,93),count(*),CHAR(91,88,93))%20FROM%20psytest.transactions%20)%20--%20%20 HTTP/1.1" 200 5086 "-" "-"

79.174.12.136 - - [28/Mar/2019:11:02:27 +0000] "GET /company/registration.php?pid=211111111111111111111111111'%20UNION%20SELECT%20(select%20CONCAT(CHAR(91,88,93),count(*),CHAR(91,88,93))%20FROM%20psytest.mail_templates%20)%20--%20%20 HTTP/1.1" 200 58 "-" "-"
```

I blocked this IP 79.174.12.136 and for the last 4 hours, there has been no further attempt.

However, I want to be sure that there is no malware lying there... How to investigate and fix it?

Can anyone provide some guidance please?

Comment: You need to fix the vulnerability in `/company/registration.php` that allowed the breach. It's just going to happen again.

Comment: Here are some tools that can help find vulnerabilities in PHP files: https://geekflare.com/php-security-scanner/

Comment: You should try posting this question over here: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The vulnerability is fixed... in fact, I deleted everything in the file (it was not an important file anyway) and now it is not processing anything.

Comment: But still , my server get choked of requests and it stops responding...

Comment: The vulnerability may have been fixed, but it seems very odd for this request to return `200 OK` if that is true.  From the Guard Duty report, it sounds like your server has been compromised... and a compromised server cannot be fixed.  You don't "remove" malware and keep the server. https://serverfault.com/q/218005/153161

Comment: Thank you Michael, going by the advice of experienced and learned professionals like you. I have terminated the server and started a new one. Currently in process of checking if all my custom files and configurations are in place.